# 'web:' is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying the getting your first django app in heroku. There it is mentioned 'Use a Procfile, in the root directory of your application, to explicitly declare what command should be executed to start your app'.
The command is "web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -"
And the error I see is 'web:' is not recognised as an internal or external command.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 12):

You're supposed to put that command into a file called Procfile, not type it into the terminal.

Comment: Silly me!! I did it. Thanks for the answer!!